# how do I lock an elasticsearch document using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm using the official elasticsearch python module.
How do I lock a document to ensure that my partial update is safe in a multi-user system?

Comment: This should get you started https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/concurrency-solutions.html

Comment: Hi. I checked out that article before I posted my question. I can't see from the article how it should be done using python elasticsearch module.